# Calculate $a_n = \binom{n}{2} + \binom{2}{n}$

Tags: combinatorics, power-series, generating-functions

> Calculate $a_n = \binom{n}{2} + \binom{2}{n}$

Could you give me a hint how to start solving this equation? How can I expand $\binom{2}{n}$?

Definition of $\binom{a}{b}=\frac{a \cdot (a-1) \cdots (a-b+1)}{b!}$ where $a \in \mathbb{C}$. We don't use Gamma function.

Comment: What context are you working in? That would help us find the right generalization of the choose function

Comment: It's in a context of combinatorics. I've added a definition of $\binom{a}{b}$ which we use.

Comment: Is $n$ an integer? Is it nonnegative?

Comment: @dash have you used the Gamma function in this class before?

Comment: It's not specified. But from definition $a \in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @StellaBiderman No, we didn't use Gamma function.

Answer (score 6):

$$
a_0=\color{lightgrey}{\binom 02}+\binom 20=0+1=1\\
a_1=\color{lightgrey}{\binom 12}+\binom 21=0+2=2\\
a_2=\binom 22+\binom 22=1+1=2\\
a_3=\binom 32+\color{lightgrey}{\binom 23}=3+0=3\\
a_4=\binom 42+\color{lightgrey}{\binom 24}=6+0=6\\
\vdots$$

Comment: Dunno, but maybe $a_0$ should be exposed also. Nice formatting.

Comment: @drhab - Thank you. $a_0$ included now.

Answer (score 2):

It depends a bit on the context you are coming from, but $\binom{2}{n}$ is $0$ for $n>2$ under the combinatorial definition. I would guess that is the appropriate decision here.

If you've used the gamma function before, it's also possible to use that to generalize the choose function.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $n\leq 2$ and $n$ has to be poitive integer equal to $0$ or greater that leaves us with $3$ possible options.

Comment: Why only 3 possible options? We have $\binom{a}{b}$ defined as $\frac{a \cdot (a-1) \cdots (a-b+1)}{b!}$. It can go to negative values.

Comment: @dash realize that $2\cdot1\cdot0\cdot(-1)\cdots=0$

Comment: Ok, now I realize this. How can I use this fact to construct generating function?